# Transformation in xaml for windows 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am creating dynamic images on canvas . T want to translate them and rotate them on button click . Translating working fine but when I rotating it its gives error like this 
Additional information: 
Unable to cast object of type 
'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.TranslateTransform'
 to type 
'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.RotateTransform'.
 Here is my code

Image i = new Image();             ***// Global variable for selecting***

```
 private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  // For creating images 
        {
            int i = 0;

            Image image = new Image();
            string url = "ms-appx:///Assets/1.png";
            BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage();

            bm.UriSource = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
            image.Source = bm;
            image.Height = Double.NaN;
            image.Width = Double.NaN;
            image.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX | ManipulationModes.TranslateY | ManipulationModes.Rotate;
            image.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();
            image.Name = "img" + i;
            image.Tapped += select;
            image.ManipulationDelta += DragableItem_ManipulationDelta;
            DrawCanvas.Children.Add(image);

            i++;   
        }

private void select(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)    // selecting of image
        {
            i = (Image)sender;
        }



private void rotate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)        //rotating
        {
            if (i != null)
            {

                var translate = (RotateTransform)i.RenderTransform;
                translate.CenterY = 0;
                translate.CenterX = 0;
                translate.Angle = 45;
                i.RenderTransform = translate;
            }
        }



    void DragableItem_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)   // translating code 
            {
                var name = (Image)sender;

                var translate = (TranslateTransform)name.RenderTransform;
                translate.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
    translate.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
}



need help stuck here for a long time ??
```

Comment: BTW with 17 Questions on Stack Overflow you should really register an account and also accept at least some of your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your `RenderTransform` to a `TranslateTransform` and then trying to cast it to a `RotateTransform` (as the error states). You should probably use a `CompositeTransform` instead or use a `TransformGroup` with both of the transform types in it.

Comment: Change `image.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();` to `image.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();`, then replace the `(TranslateTransform)` and `(RotateTransform)` casts  with a `(CompositeTransform)` one. Then replace `Angle` property with `Rotation`and `X/Y` properties with `TranslateX/TranslateY` since these are the respective analogs of the properties of `RotateTransform` and `TranslateTransform` on the `CompositeTransform` class.